# Using a field gotten from another SELECT in a CASE

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to get the following working?

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id) AS foos
CASE
WHEN foos <= 0 THEN 0
WHEN foos > 0 THEN 1
END
AS isFoos
FROM table1
```

The only way I got it working is this:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id) AS foos
CASE
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id) <= 0 THEN 0
WHEN (SELECT COUNT(foo) FROM table2 WHERE table1.id = table2.id) > 0 THEN 1
END
AS isFoos
FROM table1
```

And it looks absolutely horrible.

Note that the example doesn't describe my problematic SQL query, it describes the syntax I want to get out of the query.

Thanks :)

EDIT: Fixed the SQL to better explain the problem.

EDIT 2: Here's the fiddle, I hope it helps.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18a45d/2

The fiddle contains products and productlines. Products can be made in multiple lines and lines can make multiple products.

The pr_connected shows the amount of lines that should be working with the product and the SELECT count shows how many lines are actually working with the product.

The db I work with has some flaws and they can't be fixed due to the amount of code written on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to use the new query based on your update and your `sqlfiddle`. I am going to use a **subquery** but with only one `COUNT(*)` aggregate function and it will have the same result as yours.

```
SELECT pr_id, pr_name, connected, 
 CASE
  WHEN connected <= 0 THEN "RED"
  WHEN connected < pr_connected THEN "YELLOW"
  WHEN connected >= pr_connected THEN "GREEN"
 END as Status
FROM (
   SELECT pr_id, pr_name, pr_connected, 
     ( SELECT COUNT(pl_id) FROM product_line WHERE pl_product_id = pr_id) AS connected
       FROM product
       GROUP BY pr_name 
      ) tt
```

Check my <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/690260/5)</kbd>

Comment: You're welcome @TeroHeiskanen. Glad to be of help. Happy coding and GOD bless.

Comment: I wonder if there is any performance difference between my original solution (SELECT for each case) and your solution? I don't mind the looks of SQL query as long as it performs well.

Comment: @TeroHeiskanen Mine is faster check the `View Execution Plan` SqlFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(COUNT('foo') > 0, 1, 0) as `isFoos` FROM `table1`
```

OR

```
SELECT
  `t`.`foos`,
  IF(`t`.`foos` > 0, 1, 0) as `isFoos`
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(`x`) AS `foos` FROM `stackoverflow`) as `t`
```

Comment: This is why I said I need this exact query to work. I knew I could've used IF in this case but in my code it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
select email,
case 
when count(email) > 2 then 55
when count(email) < 2 then 33
end 
as cc
from supportContacts
group by email
```

I have put up a SQL fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94e3dd/10

Comment: Sorry, it seems my SQL didn't explain the problem well enough. Please, check the edited SQL.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle (like mine above) with sample table structure and some data so we can work it out. I have problem seeing how are your tables related.

Comment: Sure, it will have to wait until next week though.